# Chrome shows page shifted left

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

Courtesy of goal.com

Check the pointer that I drew. It doesn't point the right arrow (->), however, it looks like hover on that arrow (arrow turns into green color). Moreover, when I press at that area, it will be directed to link that is specified by that button.

Another bug is on the scroll bar. The display show the scroll bar is shifted left, so there is a gap. However, the area that can be clicked remain at the right end of the page.

Comment: the first question that you didn't address is "do you have any userscripts or extensions installed"?

Comment: FYI: can not repro.  Using Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m

Comment: this seems to be this is a bug with Chrome's [composition engine](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140239&q=double%20scrollbars&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary) though I can't repro on Version 23.0.1251.2 dev-m. See if [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140500#c10) helps

Comment: jcolebrand: I dont have any userscripts or extensions installed.
btw, what does "repro" stand for?

@Sathya: Thank for the link that you gave. the comment that was given by sied...@chromium.org really help me and the problem was solved.
"in chrome://plugins, click the "+" sign next to Details on the top right to expand all information. In the Flash category, search for the plugin with the Location that ends in "... PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll", and try disabling it."
I hope it will help you guys whoever face the same problem :D

Comment: @davidsinjaya you should add that as an answer. By repro I mean I'm not able to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Sathya in comment, I will put it as an answer

In Chrome `chrome://plugins`, click the "**+**" sign next to **Details** on the top right to expand all information. In the Flash category, search for the plugin with the Location that ends in `... PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll`, and try disabling it.

I hope it will help you guys whoever face the same problem :D