# Weird offset in google chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome shows page shifted left](https://superuser.com/questions/469619/chrome-shows-page-shifted-left)

my browser has a click to visual offset to the right on many websites! The Map should end at the scrollbar. This spacing there is about the offset I have click to follows links or to croll in tabs.

[image]

To open links or scroll tabs I have always to click next to the button instead of on it.
I uninstalled Google chrome and deleted all Google appdata from local, roaming and local low folder, but it didn't help. I had my Google account synced with my Google account. So maybe its some kind of strange setting?
Did anyone have the same problem in the past? Any Suggestions what I could do?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? Any user styles/CSS overrides?

Comment: You may also try disabling GPU rendering at chrome://flags and see if that helps. You can verify whether GPU rendering is enabled/disabled by going to chrome://gpu .

Comment: I tried a lot of flag settings, but hardware accelerated seems to stay enaled?

Comment: I don't have any extensions, and also tried fresh installed chrome without any sync.

Comment: looks like this [Chrome shows page shifted left](http://superuser.com/q/469619)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lenovo notebook has a switchable graphic card. An ATI HD6630M and mobile Intel HD 3000.
I can fix the problem when switching to the ATI HD6630M.

So the problem seems as mentioned by alquixotic with the hardware rendering. So if anybody has fixed it with the Intel I would be glad to hear?

Also a working flags setting to disable hardware acceleration would be helpful.

Right now I'm lucky to have a second graphics card!