# Chrome: Black Screen of Death

Tags: google-chrome

I dont know when it started to happen. The screen will turn into full black when a page include javascript (I think so). I cannot open Youtube videos, but I can still see the source code and the pointer to find links and buttons and I can hear the sound of video. I have tried to clear my cache and reinstalled to the latest version, but nothing seems work. Moreover, I have disabled the Pepperflash Player as well, but it did not help.

This my chrome version
Google Chrome   22.0.1229.79 (Official Build 158531)

OS  Windows

WebKit  537.4 (@129177)

JavaScript  V8 3.12.19.11

Flash   11.3.31.331

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like a flash problem to me. Try updating flash, or reinstalling it.

Comment: @m4573r : i have updated to the latest flash. but it does not work

Comment: As google chrome has it's own version of flash built into it, that will not help, sounds more or less like a problem in that channels version of chrome and if so you will have to use a different version of chrome like the dev channel or wait till the latest update.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome comes with PepperFlash, which seems to be a problem for a lot of people. Try going to `about:plugins`, click on "Details" in the top right corner, and scroll to where you see "Adobe Flash Player" listed. If there are two files, disable the PepperFlash variant, restart the browser, and see if that solves the issue.

If it does, you may want to consider posting a bug report for PepperFlash [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

I have personally had issues with PepperFlash making the video jumpy.

Comment: i have faced this problem that I faced before, and solved it with disabling the Pepper flash player
http://superuser.com/questions/469619/chrome-shows-page-shifted-left


however, i have disabled it now but I faced another problem :(

Comment: If it's not PepperFlash, I'm not quite sure what it could be. You should update your question, though, to show that you have PepperFlash disabled. It would also probably help if you posted the `about:version` stats from "Google Chrome" to "Flash".

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to settings.
2. Go to advanced settings.
3. Click on advanced settings and wait...
4. Click on reset.
5. Restart your computer.
6. Problem is gone!